# How to get minimum number of moves to solve `game of fifteen`?

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix, time-complexity, adjacency-matrix

I was reading about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#Solvability) and thought to form an algorithm to find the minimum number of moves to solve this.

Constraints I made: An `N X N` matrix having one empty slot ,say `0`, would be plotted having numbers `0 to n-1`.

Now we have to recreate this matrix and form the matrix having numbers in increasing order from left to right beginning from the top row and have the last element `0` i.e. (N X Nth)element.

For example,

```
Input :

8 4 0
7 2 5
1 3 6

Output:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
```

Now the problem is how to do this in minimum number of steps possible.
As in game(link provided) you can either move left, right, up or bottom and shift the `0`(empty slot) to corresponding position to make the final matrix.

The output to printed for this algorithm is number of steps say `M` and then `Tile`(number) moved in the direction say,  `1` for swapping with upper adjacent element, `2` for lower adjacent element, `3` for left adjacent element and `4` for right adjacent element.

Like, for

```
2     <--- order of N X N matrix
3 1
0 2
```

Answer should be: `3 4 1 2` where `3` is `M` and `4 1 2` are steps to tile movement.

So I have to minimise the complexity for this algorithm and want to find minimum number of moves. Please suggest me the most efficient approach to solve this algorithm.

**Edit:**

**What I coded in c++**, `Please see the algorithm rather than pointing out other issues in code` .

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int inDex=0,shift[100000],N,initial[500][500],final[500][500];
struct Node
{
    Node* parent;
    int mat[500][500];
    int x, y;
    int cost;
    int level;
};

Node* newNode(int mat[500][500], int x, int y, int newX,
              int newY, int level, Node* parent)
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->parent = parent;
    memcpy(node->mat, mat, sizeof node->mat);
    swap(node->mat[x][y], node->mat[newX][newY]);
    node->cost = INT_MAX;
    node->level = level;
    node->x = newX;
    node->y = newY;
    return node;
}

int row[] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
int col[] = { 0, -1, 0, 1 };

int calculateCost(int initial[500][500], int final[500][500])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
              if (initial[i][j] && initial[i][j] != final[i][j])
                count++;
    return count;

}

int isSafe(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N);
}
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs->cost + lhs->level) > (rhs->cost + rhs->level);
    }
};

void solve(int initial[500][500], int x, int y,
           int final[500][500])
{
    priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, comp> pq;
    Node* root = newNode(initial, x, y, x, y, 0, NULL);
    Node* prev = newNode(initial,x,y,x,y,0,NULL);
    root->cost = calculateCost(initial, final);
    pq.push(root);
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        Node* min = pq.top();
        if(min->x > prev->x)
        {
            shift[inDex] = 4;
            inDex++;
        }
        else if(min->x < prev->x)
        {
            shift[inDex] = 3;
            inDex++;
        }
        else if(min->y > prev->y)
        {
            shift[inDex] = 2;
            inDex++;
        }
        else if(min->y < prev->y)
        {
            shift[inDex] = 1;
            inDex++;
        }
        prev = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (min->cost == 0)
        {
            cout << min->level << endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (isSafe(min->x + row[i], min->y + col[i]))
            {
                Node* child = newNode(min->mat, min->x,
                              min->y, min->x + row[i],
                              min->y + col[i],
                              min->level + 1, min);

                child->cost = calculateCost(child->mat, final);
                pq.push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    cin >> N;
    int i,j,k=1;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            cin >> initial[j][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            final[j][i] = k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    final[N-1][N-1] = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 1,a[100][100];
    solve(initial, x, y, final);
    for(i=0;i<inDex;i++)
    {
        cout << shift[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this above code I am checking for each child node which has the minimum cost(`how many numbers are misplaced from the final matrix numbers`).

I want to make this algorithm further efficient and reduce it's time complexity. Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this sounds a lot like a homework problem, I'll lend a bit of help.

For significantly small problems, like your 2x2 or 3x3, you can just brute force it. Basically, you do every possible combination with every possible move, track how many turns each took, and then print out the smallest.

To improve on this, maintain a list of solved solutions, and then any time you make a possible move, if that moves already done, stop trying that one since it can't possible be the smallest.

Example, say I'm in this state (flattening your matrix to a string for ease of display):

```
5736291084
6753291084
5736291084
```

Notice that we're back to a state we've seen before. That means it can't possible be the smallest move, because the smallest would be done without returning to a previous state.

You'll want to create a tree doing this, so you'd have something like:

```
                            134
                            529
                            870
                           /   \
                          /     \
                         /       \
                        /         \
                     134           134
                     529           520
                     807           879
                    / | \         / | \
                   /  |  X       /  X  \
                134  134  134 134  134  130
                509  529  529 502  529  524
                827  087  870 879  870  879
```

And so on. Notice I marked some with `X` because they were duplicates, and thus we wouldn't want to pursue them any further since we know they can't be the smallest.

You'd just keep repeating this until you've tried all possible solutions (i.e., all non-stopped leaves reach a solution), then you just see which was the shortest. You could also do it in parallel so you stop once any one has found a solution, saving you time.

This brute force approach won't be effective against large matrices. To solve those, you're looking at some serious software engineering. One approach you could take with it would be to break it into smaller matrices and solve that way, but that may not be the best path.

This is a tricky problem to solve at larger values, and is up there with some of the trickier NP problems out there.

---

## Start from solution, determine ranks of permuation

The reverse of above would be how you can pre-generate a list of all possible values.

Start with the solution. That has a rank of permutation of 0 (as in, zero moves):

```
012
345
678
```

Then, make all possible moves from there. All of those moves have rank of permutation of 1, as in, one move to solve.

```
                         012
0                        345
                         678
                        /   \
                       /     \
                      /       \
                   102         312
1                  345         045 
                   678         678
```

Repeat that as above. Each new level all has the same rank of permutation. Generate all possible moves (in this case, until all of your branches are killed off as duplicates).

You can then store all of them into an object. Flattening the matrix would make this easy (using JavaScript syntax just for example):

```
{
  '012345678': 0,
  '102345678': 1,
  '312045678': 1,
  '142305678': 2,
  // and so on
}
```

Then, to solve your question "minimum number of moves", just find the entry that is the same as your starting point. The rank of permutation is the answer.

This would be a good solution if you are in a scenario where you can pre-generate the entire solution. It would take time to generate, but lookups would be lightning fast (this is similar to "rainbow tables" for cracking hashes).

If you must solve on the fly (without pre-generation), then the first solution, start with the answer and work your way move-by-move until you find a solution would be better.

While the maximum complexity is O(n!), there are only O(n^2) possible solutions. Chopping off duplicates from the tree as you go, your complexity will be somewhere in between those two, probably in the neighborhood of O(n^3) ~ O(2^n)

Comment: Well, you are just providing me naive brute-force approach which comes in mind of every beginner who would try to solve this. Still, thanks for your effort. Of course I am trying to build this algorithm for N up to 200-400 at least. PS: Not a homework!

Comment: If you go through the problem link it's given there it's NP hard for larger N already.
`For larger versions of the n-puzzle, finding a solution is easy, but the problem of finding the shortest solution is NP-hard. It is also NP-hard to approximate the fewest slides within an additive constant, but there is a polynomial-time constant-factor approximation. It's mentioned there already. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the entire Wikipedia article. If you know it's NP-hard, why would you ask for a solution on Stack Overflow. Those are doctorate level research problems trying to solve them. That's why I assumed you were a beginner with a homework problem. Also, the "brute force" method I gave you is still going to be the basis of any solution. It's just going to be a matter of optimizing it and finding shortcuts. There likely isn't a magical algorithm that just solves an NP-hard problem in O(1) or anywhere close. This is why people are working so hard on building quantum computers.

Comment: I do not want the complete solution, I just need some suggestions(`shortcuts` and `optimised` as you said) on how to make it efficient like the other answer suggested of thinking every matrix which has one tile shifted connected with it's pair through an edge and apply `rank of permutation` for each node but still i don't get it fully.Stack Overflow allows user to ask for approaches to solve NP-Hard problems approximations, and so that community can participate and do some development and such algorithms helps public to develop their own problems while doing research.

Comment: I just need some approximated method to make this algorithm efficient.

Comment: If you have read my problem carefully, we also need steps that has taken place like `up down left right` , how to get them?

Comment: For that, instead of storing them in a finalized list, store them as a tree, then just search the tree for your solution, then walk up the tree for each step. You could figure out which direction you moved by comparing each step to one another.

Comment: Moreover, the `0` is at the last index. Just pointing out what question was.

Comment: The solution you want doesn't matter. The solution could be '512368407" and the algorithm would be the same. It would just have a different start or end point.

Comment: We can further reduce improve this concept by keeping a check at each step of child node that which child has minimum number of misplaced child and go further in that branch in tree.

Comment: @AnantSharma Once you have some working code, it'd be better to head over to codereview.stackexchange.com. That's where to go when you have working code and want to make it better.

Comment: Okay! Thanks. So what should I do now remove my code from here or let it be before asking at codereview, I will provide link there?

Comment: link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166363/minimum-number-of-moves-to-solve-game-of-fifteen

Answer (score 0):

You can use BFS.

Each state is one vertex, and there is an edge between two vertices if they can transfer to each other.

For example

```
8 4 0
7 2 5
1 3 6
```

and

```
8 0 4
7 2 5
1 3 6
```

are connected.

Usually, you may want to use some numbers to represent your current state. For small grid, you can just follow the sequence of the number. For example,

```
8 4 0
7 2 5
1 3 6
```

is just `840725136`.

If the grid is large, you may consider using the rank of the permutation of the numbers as your representation of the state. For example,

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

should be `0`, as it is the first in permutation.

And

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

(which is represented by 0)
and

```
1 0 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

(which is represented by some other number X)
are connected is the same as 0 and X are connected in the graph.

The complexity of the algo should be `O(n!)` as there are at most `n!` vertices/permutations.

Comment: Please can you elaborate for large N . How to use `rank of the permutation`?

Comment: `Rank of Permutation` is simply starting with the solution, which would be 0 (as in zero steps to solve). Then making every possible move you can, each of which would be ranked 1 (as in, 1 move), then all of those do every possible move (ditch duplicates), etc. It's basically exactly what I recommended, but in reverse. This solution would let you find and cache all possible solutions for a quick lookup. However, it would take an extremely long time to solve for large N's, not to mention substantial memory. For any given NxN, there are N^2 possible results. Might be viable for 200<=N<=500.

Comment: For a matrix of NxN, there are N^2 possible solutions, so you'd have N^2 results with various rank of permutation values, and probably something approaching N^3 leaves to evaluate.

Comment: @AnantSharma, there are many existing algos, you may want to refer to https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation

Comment: @samanime, what I mean is to use the rank of a permutation to represent the state.

Comment: @AnantSharma, let's say you have a 4*4 matrix, simply flattening the matrix does not help a lot. As you will have 10, 11, 12... and 101211 is not clear as it might be 10,12,11 or 1,0,12,11 or 10,1,2,11... To resolve this problem, you may want to use the rank of the permutation to represent the state instead.

Comment: Okay! I just skim through this link I found some interesting algos, but here what bothering me is suppose after numbering `0` as in your solution , for number 1 there are 2 possibilities for `0` so I will name it number `1`(2) , now after that I have 2,2 possibilities again and sometimes 3 possibilities , i have to keep in mind that patterns do not repeat but how will i handle these numbers?and @samanime how can you say there are only N^2 possible solutions?

Comment: @JerryChou  So in what order can you decide which number should be given to which state through rank of permutation when there are more than one possible states?

Comment: If you imagine putting them in a tree like the one I mapped out, each level of the tree would all have the same rank of permuation. Solution is 0. There are 2 number 1s, 2-4 number 2s (2 would be duplicates, moving back to the original state), etc. For your question "smallest number of moves", the rank of permutation of the puzzle that matches your start state is the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with some info about generating them ahead of time. @AnantSharma

Comment: @JerryChou as you edited I agree that it will take O(n!) which is impossible to implement for N in the range of 200 to 500, so I guess this algorithm can't be performed in worst case.

Comment: @samanime Can you provide any implementation of that or pseudocode in any language?Well, we can only imagine that.

Comment: Sorry, for a question this open ended, not willing to provide code, pseudo or otherwise. But basically, you'll check each of the four directions around 0. If zero can move in a direction, that's a new leaf for the next level. After running through each level, remove duplicates, then run it again against everything in the latest level. It'll be a recursive function for sure. When you either find the solution (solution A), or run out of non-duplicates on the current level (solution B), you're done.

Comment: Take a stab at writing some code yourself and either post it here, if it doesn't work, or codereview.stackexchange.com if it does and I'm sure you can get more help.

Comment: Okay! It would take time to code I am on it, I asked because I was not getting that out of `n!` permutations how complexity is only `O(n^3)` but your solution helped me clearing that doubt, how can I approach you If I get any difficulty? BTW thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I am coding it in c++  , I will post my code here as the `answer` as soon as I am done with it.

Comment: @AnantSharma,  I just saw the range of N, in that case BFS does not apply here. Instead, I would suggest you try some randomized algorithm like Monte-Carlo Tree Search

Comment: @JerryChou @samanime I have updated my post, please provide me some idea to make it more `efficient` in terms of `time-complexity`.

Comment: visit here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166363/minimum-number-of-moves-to-solve-game-of-fifteen